# limiting the Debug info to what we want to see

Tags: c#, debugging

I cannot remember it but there is an attribute that we can add to the code where we want to debug and that way we can specify for example what properties of a class we want to see in the debug info when we hover over the variables.so if there are 30 properties then this way I can limit that window to only show the properties that we specify in the attribute for it.
hope I could explain what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [[DebuggerBrowsable]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsableattribute.aspx), or possibly [[DebuggerDisplay]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx).

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx) for an overview of these attributes.

Answer (score 1):

DebuggerDisplay and DebuggerBrowsable are probably what you are looking for.